# SPLIT command not working in apache-pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

```
initialData = load 'Weather_Report.log' using PigStorage('|') as (cityid:int,cityname:chararray,currentWeather:chararray,weatherCode:int);
SPLIT initialData INTO noRainsCities IF weatherCode ==10;
STORE noRainCities INTO 'WEATHER_ANALYTICS/TEST_OUT/NoRainCititesData';
```

PLZ HElp me out guys 
This is the error

```
2016-09-28 11:03:14,597 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1200: <line 2, column 52>  Syntax error, unexpected symbol at or near '='
```

Comment: In this case u should use filter to find noRainsCities..

Answer (score 0):

```
iniData = LOAD 'empdetail.log' using PigStorage('|') as (id:int,x:chararray,city:chararray,tech:chararray);
split iniData into a if tech=='Java',b if city=='Pune';
dump a;
dump b;
```

GUYS : SPLIT DONT WORK UNTIL 2 OR MORE CONDITIONS ARE GIVEN ;

PROBLEM SOLVED THANKS